# SocialEngine - 301 redirection of old site pages .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, socialengine

I installed SocialEngine to replace an old CMS. The problem is that a lot of old URLs are present in the search engines. I would like to redirect them to the corresponding URLs on the current website (because at this time they only redirect to the homepage).

All the content of my old CMS was imported into SE, so each old page has its equivalent now.
For example : 
old address : /index.php?mod=news&ac=commentaires&id=367
new address :  /articles/367

I tried to add in my .htaccess something like :

```
redirectmatch 301 index.php?mod=news&ac=commentaires&id=([0-9]+) http://www.nailissima.fr/articles/$1
```

But it doesn't work. When I type the old address, it still redirects to the homepage, not to the corresponding article.

Would you please help me to solve that ?

Here is my .htaccess :

```
# $Id: .htaccess 7539 2010-10-04 04:41:38Z john $

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # Get rid of index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

  # Rewrite all directory-looking urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

  # Try to route missing files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

# sends requests /index.php/path/to/module/ to "index.php"
# AcceptPathInfo On

# @todo This may not be effective in some cases
FileETag Size
```

Thank you in advance !

Best regards

Comment: Can you post your edited htaccess where you added your rule?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have the problem with order of your redirects instructions.

First disable with comments all your current general rules and try your new redirects alone.

If they work, then attentivly think where you should place them.

[L] at the end of instruction makes it last, so it this instruction matches, not further will process.

Using this, write more detailed instructions first, and more general later, otherwise, you can meet situation when further instructions overright your current!

Comment: Thank you foryour quick answer !

Unfortunately I tried to disable all the content of the .htaccess, and  put only the redirectmatch code on first line, even this doesn't work : lots of menus and links of the site are broken, but when I type an old address, it still redirects to SocialEngine's homepage instead of the corresponding new page :(